# Bndtools Local repository view is empty

Tags: bndtools

I am using Eclipse Luna with bndtools. When I add bundles to the 'Local Repository' the repository view is empty. I cannot see the bundles listed there.

Any solution ?

Comment: How do you add the bundles to the Local Repository? Which version of bndtools are you using.